# Public Live streaming on Facebook- Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I have created an app in which app users can do live streaming on their Facebook account, things are working well but when live streaming is on `Privacy` is being set to `{Private automatically}`.

Here is my code:

```
val request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/$userId/live_videos",
        JSONObject("{\"title\":\"Test\",\"description\":\"This is the live video for today.\", \"value\":\"EVERYONE\"}")
    ) {
        val url = it.jsonObject.get("secure_stream_url")
        val id = it.jsonObject.get("id")
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: The default privacy setting for content created through an app, is determined by what privacy level the user chooses in the login dialog, the first time you ask for any publishing-related permission. Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, edit your app settings there, regarding “Who can see you use this app?”, and see if that changes things.

Comment: @CBroe I have done this already but it is also not working and please suggest any programmatic solution

Comment: Just to be clear - are we talking about the actual privacy setting of the broadcast video here - or is maybe your app simply in development mode, so that any users without a role in the app won’t see any content created through it yet?

Comment: App is in development mode